# android send sms from webinterface

Tags: android, sms

I'm building an android webapp using webview and added webinterface class.

Here is my code :

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }



    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void SendSMS(String msg,String PhoneNumber) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,
                "sending",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(PhoneNumber, null, msg, null, null);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    "SMS not sent, please try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

MainActiviy :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        if (checkconnection()) {
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        } else {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "אין חיבור לאינטרנט";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public boolean checkconnection() {


        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
         return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Form Javascript I call

`Android.showToast('test')` <=======  this works fine

`Android.SendSMS('0587070580','test sms')` <========== not working

No exception is raised.

Comment: Hi user, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't make clear what the actual problem is. If you could isolate the code responsible and edit your question to provide only the code directly related to the problem, people will be more able to help you find a solution. :)

Comment: Have you given the SMS permission ?

Comment: Have you tried with `English` words in SMS ?

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. yes, i've tried english and gave SEND_SMS permissions. if I send the SMS from oncreate it send the sms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation on your `SendSMS()` method.

> Starting from API level JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above, only methods explicitly marked with this annotation are available to the Javascript code.

Source: [JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html)